# Disable Wordpress auto <p> tag for specific input element only

Tags: css, wordpress, input, focus

I know I can prevent Wordpress from adding `<p>` tags entirely. However, this is **not an option** as I have to deal with an entire post archive which counts on these tags, and I am not going back in time to fix every post manually.

So my question is, how can I disable the auto `<p>` tag for one page or even one element only? Specifically, I am using the CSS code `.jumpsection:focus + #section-nav-menu {visibility: visible;}` for the HTML below:

```
<div id="section-nav">
  <input type="text" value="GO TO SECTION" class="jumpsection"><p></p><!-- Grrr...Wordpress :( -->
  <div id="section-nav-menu">
    <ul class="contain">
      <li class="section-nav-item"><a href="#s1">SECTION 1</a></li>
      <li class="section-nav-item"><a href="#s2">SECTION 2</a></li>
      <li class="section-nav-item"><a href="#s3">SECTION 3</a></li>
      <li class="section-nav-item"><a href="#s4">SECTION 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In other words, if I click on the input "GO TO SECTION", the section-nav-menu changes from `visibility: hidden;` to `visibility: visible;` which worked before I turned the auto `<p>` tag back on. But as you can see in the HTML, Wordpress adds `<p></p>` after the input element, which to my big frustration breaks the functionality of `:focus`.

If temporarily disabling the auto tags is not possible, any workaround for this specific problem (getting this pure CSS on-click dropdown to work) is also very appreciated!!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `~` selector. Like this:

```
.jumpsection:focus ~ #section-nav-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Demo [here](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/GNXKLB)

[Here is some info about the ~ selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: this is perfect for my specific situation! Elegant and simple :) I upvoted this, though I will reserve the best answer to match the initial question. Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure if javascript is necessary. Perhaps the the wpautop function in \wp-includes\formatting.php can be manipulated to avoid elements of a certain class? Thanks for the link about the ~ selector by the way!

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a good point. I forgot you were in wordpress! Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26571012/5561605

Answer (score 0):

*You may* be interested in this little **plugin**.

[Don't Muck My Markup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dont-muck-my-markup/)

Here's the **official description**:

> Don't Muck My Markup lets you disable all auto-generated HTML markup from your posts and pages on a page-by-page basis.

In a nutshell:

It **adds** a very simple **box** to the **editor page** that allows you to **turn off the automatic mark up** that the WordPress engine inserts.

The options include

- turning off all automatic mark up **for all pages** 
  (which you don't want
  to do )
- turning off all automatic mark up for **the specific page you're
  editing**. (which is what I understand you want to be able to do)

Comment: @I Love CSS: Thanks for the suggestion! Though my specific problem is solved by changing the CSS, this might be useful for the future. Hope I won't need it though, as I like to keep the number of plugins to a minimum :)